# Gesture events from iPad magic keyboard

Tags: javascript, webkit, ipados

I have a web app where the user can pinch zoom using gestures. It is coded in javascript and uses gestureStart, gestureChange and gestureEnd. It works nicely when the user pinch zooms by using fingers on the touch screen, but when I try pinch zooming on a iPad Magic Keyboard I never receive any of the gestureXxxx events.

Is there a different set of events for the Magic Keyboard, or what else can I be doing wrong?

Comment: Did you ever find an answer?  Driving me crazy

Comment: No, I guess it must be an Apple bug?!